# How to write numpy array list result from one function into second Excel write function in Python using openpyxl?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, openpyxl, fuzzywuzzy

I would like to ask a question regarding a logic that I have been developing for the past couple of weeks, unfortunately was not able to produce the desired result.

The goal of my project is to extract data from two separate columns from different spreadsheets, use the fuzzy wuzzy string matching algorithm to estimate the percentage match between the row values and then output the result in Excel.

However, my case is a bit trickier - every row from the first spreadsheet column I have to compare with each row from the second spreadsheet column. By estimating the similarity ratio, I have to then filter it by using sort and find the first 3 matches which register the higher percentage (limit = 3), then output the result. But since I will be working with enormous amounts of data, was wondering if there was a way I could first estimate the string similarity ratio via the fuzzy wuzzy module. I am using pandas and numpy to extract and reformat the column data into data frames and then reformat it to numpy arrays for faster performance.

My question is - how can I perform the actions described above and after done, write into an Excel file the matching pairs in neighboring columns (1st match number - 1st match %, 2nd match number - 2nd match % and so on)?

Here is my code. Would highly appreciate any hints or pieces of advice :)

```py
    import pandas as pd
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
    from fuzzywuzzy import process
    import numpy as np
    import openpyxl


    list_POData = np.array(purchaseOrderItemDescription)
    list_MaterialsData = np.array(materialDescription)

    matCounter = 0
    counter = 0
    while matCounter <= len(list_POData) or matCounter > len(list_POData):
        if matCounter >= len(list_POData):
            break
        else:

            def first_func(query, match, limit=3):
                percent_Match = process.extract(query, match, limit=limit, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
                return percent_Match


            # Counter to increment the values inside appended list/+1 after each iteration.
            def iterator_Func():
                global first_Match, second_Match, third_Match, counter
                for materialElement in range(len(list_MaterialsData)):
                    new_list = [materialElement]
                    new_array = np.hstack(purchaseOrderItemDescription[0:])
                    array_appendedValues = np.append(new_array, new_list)
                    n = 30000
                    array_appendedValues = np.append(array_appendedValues[:n], array_appendedValues[:n + 1])
                    first_Match = np.array(
                        first_func(array_appendedValues.astype(str)[counter], array_appendedValues, limit=3)[0])
                    counter += 1
                    second_Match = np.array(
                        first_func(array_appendedValues.astype(str)[counter], array_appendedValues, limit=3)[1])
                    counter += 1
                    third_Match = np.array(
                        first_func(array_appendedValues.astype(str)[counter], array_appendedValues, limit=3)[2])
                    return [first_Match[0], first_Match[1]], [second_Match[0], second_Match[1]], [third_Match[0],
                                                                                                  third_Match[1]]


            listResult = iterator_Func()
            matCounter += 1

    # Function to write in Excel spreadsheet
    def write_Results():
        global materialDescription, listResult, materialNumber
        resultFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('Spreadhsheet1.xlsx', read_only=False)
        firstSheet = resultFile.worksheets[0]
        # Hardcoded value of starting column to insert values
        col = 20
        firstSheet.cell(row=1, column=col).value = "Material Number"
        firstSheet.cell(row=1, column=col + 1).value = "Material Number Match"
        firstSheet.cell(row=1, column=col + 2).value = "Top 3 Matches, %"
        for index, materialItem in enumerate(list_MaterialsData):
            firstSheet.cell(row=2 + index * 3, column=col).value = materialNumber.tolist()[index]
            for innerIndex, innerItem in enumerate(listResult):
                firstSheet.cell(row=2 + index * 3 + innerIndex, column=col + 1).value = listResult[0][0]
                firstSheet.cell(row=2 + index * 3 + innerIndex, column=col + 2).value = listResult[0][1]
                firstSheet.cell(row=2 + index * 3 + 1, column=col + 1).value = listResult[1][0]
                firstSheet.cell(row=2 + index * 3 + 1, column=col + 2).value = listResult[1][1]
                firstSheet.cell(row=2 + index * 3 + 2, column=col + 2).value = listResult[2][0]
                firstSheet.cell(row=2 + index * 3 + 2, column=col + 2).value = listResult[2][1]
        resultFile.save('Spreadsheet1.xlsx')

    write_Results()
```

Comment: Hello there! Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're new here, so you may be a little unfamiliar with how everything works. People can answer you much more easily if you manage to isolate the little bit of code that you're trying to get help and insights (your particular Excel formula perhaps) Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get a few tips. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the advice, unfortunately, I think no one will be able to understand what is it that I want to achieve with the logic with only sections of the code